# Creating a React Native app from an existing React web project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to figure out how to add a react native project into my already existing react project. I want to be able to re-use functions that already exist so I don't want to build an entirely new RN project, but just incorporate that into my react project. I can't find any documentation on how to do something like that or what to use. I'd prefer to be able to integrate expo since that would take out a lot of the configuration work, but if that isn't possible I'm open to other ideas too. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get started with this?

Comment: Move the shared functionality to a separate project and have both react projects use the new project as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You might want to check out what's called "monorepo"

It will help you navigate, manage and maintain multiple typescript/javascript/nodejs projects in the same repository.

Here are a few links that will help you get started.
https://dev.to/mxro/the-ultimate-guide-to-typescript-monorepos-5ap7
https://lerna.js.org/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-monorepos-with-lerna

**Option 2(a bit old but still works)**
You can use what's called a Git submodule. For example, if you build central UI component repo and want to distribute it or clone it for your project, you can use it.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

**Option 3**

Depending on your scale of work, you can also create your private nodejs modules and put the repo in package.json for traditional installation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight, I'll look into these!